# order records by month name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to order my results by month name but it is not getting ordered in sql server .

my query:

```
select DATEname(month,signdate) as month1, 
       COUNT(contractid) as noofcontracts, sum(loanamt) as totalloan ,
       min(loanamt) as minloan 
from contracts
group by DATEname(month,signdate) order by DATEname(month, signdate);
```

i have tried using datepart function but then it is giving error

```
select DATEname(month,signdate) as month1, 
      COUNT(contractid) as noofcontracts, sum(loanamt) as totalloan ,
      min(loanamt) as minloan 
from contracts
group by DATEname(month,signdate)
order by DATEPART(m,signdate) ;
```

> error:Column "contracts.signdate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

output which im getting:

```
month   count loan_amt min_loan
April     2    14998    4999
February  1    8189     8189
June      5    133645   2599
```

May       2    21947    10048

Desired output:
February record should come first and so on..

Pls help.

Comment: i have already used datepart but not working

Comment: April, February, June looks like alphabetical order to me. That would make "i want to order my results by month name" appear to be inaccurate, e.g. that you want to order by month _number_, not _name_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an aggregation function for the `order by`:

```
order by min(signdate);
```

Alternatively, include the month number in the `group by`:

```
group by datename(month, signdate), month(signdate)
order by month(signdate)
```

Note that you have the month in the query without the year -- either as a filter or a `group by` expression.  This usually indicates an problem with the query logic.

Comment: this works, getting results as expected. thanks gordon